# How to turn off hyperlinks in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to disable hyperlinks in VSCode so badly because every time I copy a link, I use cursor and `cmd + c`, then vscode determines that I use `cmd + click` to follow a link and open in browser. That drives me crazy! And I find no clue to turn off hyperlinks in VSCode.

[image]

Comment: @Alex lmao, no it's not.

Answer (score 27):

You are looking for :

> // Controls whether the editor should detect links and make them clickable
>
> "editor.links": true,

That is the default, make yours false.  I do not know when this was added to VSCode.